# Split one column into two columns and retaining the seperator

Tags: regex, r, split, dataframe

I have a very large data array:

```
'data.frame':   40525992 obs. of  14 variables:    
 $ INSTNM     : Factor w/ 7050 levels "A   W Healthcare Educators"     
 $ Total      : Factor w/ 3212 levels "1","10","100",    
 $ Crime_Type : Factor w/ 72 levels "MURD11","NEG_M11",    
 $ Count      : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

The Crime_Type column contains the type of Crime and the Year, so "MURD11" is Murder in 2011. These are college campus crime statistics my kid is analyzing for her school project, I am helping when she is stuck. I am currently stuck at creating a clean data file she can analyze

Once i converted the wide file (all crime types '9' in columns) to a long file using 'gather' the file size is going from 300MB to **8 GB.** The file I am working on is 8GB. do you that is the problem. How do i convert it to a data.table for faster processing?

What I want to do is to `split` this 'Crime_Type' column into two columns 'Crime_Type' and 'Year'. The data contains alphanumeric and numbers. There are also some special characters like NEG_M which is 'Negligent Manslaughter'.

We will replace the full names later but can some one suggest on how I separate

MURD11 --> MURD and 11 (in two columns)
NEG_M10  --> NEG_M and 10 (in two columns)

etc...

I have tried using,

```
df <- separate(totallong, Crime_Type, into = c("Crime", "Year"), sep = "[:digit:]", extra = "merge")
df <- separate(totallong, Crime_Type, into = c("Year", "Temp"), sep = "[:alpha:]", extra = "merge")
```

The first one separates the Crime as it looks for numbers. The second one does not work at all.

I also tried

```
df$Crime_Type<- apply (strsplit(as.character(df$Crime_Type), split="[:digit:]"))
```

That does not work at all. I have gone through many posts on stack-overflow and thats where I got these commands but I am now truly stuck and would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `tidyr` already (as evidenced by `separate`), try the `extract` function, which, given a regex, puts each captured group into a new column. The 'Crime_Type' is all the non-numeric stuff, and the 'Year' is the numeric stuff. Adjust the regex accordingly.

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df, 'Crime_Type', into=c('Crime', 'Year'), regex='^([^0-9]+)([0-9]+)$')
```

Comment: The code is executing indefinitely, when I hit stop it comes out. Ran it for 10 min. I dont understand though. this should run....

Comment: Using an example `df=data.frame(Crime_Type=c('MURD11', 'NEG_M10'))` it works, so perhaps something to do with yoru dataframe. Do all codes fit this pattern? Is the dataframe quite large? Rather than splitting *each row* of `df$Crime_Type`, you may be better to split the **levels** of `df$Crime_Type` (as there are far fewer) then using this as a lookup table to assign the new columns. This would prevent so much regex matching, at least. Without a reproducible example, I can't help you much further.

Comment: Thanks, the frame is large 'data.frame':   40525992 obs. of  14 variables: Will it work if I change the expression to [:digit:], as there are some '_' in the names we need to retain.  I will try to see if I can get it to work. Appreciate your help

Comment: In that case, our code is fine, but the problem is your big dataset (not mentioned in your question). Go with `data.table`, and only do the split for each unique `Crime_Type`, not for each row in the table. In `data.table` this could be via `, by=Crime_Type]`; if using `tidyr` as I have done, use also `dplyr` and `%>% group_by(Crime_Type)` first. `data.table` will be much faster and given the size of your df, you should use it instead of base R or dplyr/tidyr.

Comment: You are correct, I just saw and once i converted the wide file (all crime types '9' in columns) to a long file using 'gather' the file size is going from 300MB to 8 GB. The file I am working on is 8GB. do you that is the problem. How do i convert it to a data.table for faster processing?

Comment: Thanks Guys.. solved the problem, the command worked beautifully. the problem was data size i had messed up in the 'merge' command creating duplicated increasing the file size, fixed that and now the same command works great.. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hi Mathematical I used your command to solve this problem, and it was working fine, today when i ran the code its giving me a error - "Error: Regex didn't match at 143857, 143858, 143859" Do you know why that would be the case?

Comment: Because the regex doesn't match? See what df$Crime_Type is at 143857, 143858, 143859....

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, one option would be to create a unique delimiter between the non-numeric and numeric part.  We can capture as a group the non-numeric (`[^0-9]+`) and numeric (`[0-9]+`) characters by wrapping it inside the parentheses (`(..)`) and in the replacement we use `\\1` for the first capture group, followed by a `,` and the second group (`\\2`).  This can be used as input vector to `read.table` with `sep=','` to read as two columns.

```
 df1 <- read.table(text=gsub('([^0-9]+)([0-9]+)', '\\1,\\2', 
                   totallong$Crime_Type),sep=",", col.names=c('Crime', 'Year'))
 df1
 #   Crime Year
 #1  MURD   11
 #2 NEG_M   11
```

If we need, we can `cbind` with the original dataset

```
cbind(totallong, df1)
```

Or in `base R`, we can use `strsplit` with `split` specifying the boundary between non-number (`(?<=[^0-9])`) and a number (`(?=[0-9])`).  Here we use `lookarounds` to match the boundary.  The output will be a `list`, we can `rbind` the `list` elements with `do.call(rbind` and convert it to `data.frame`

```
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(totallong$Crime_Type), 
                        split="(?<=[^0-9])(?=[0-9])", perl=TRUE)))
#     V1 V2
#1  MURD 11
#2 NEG_M 11
```

---

Or another option is `tstrsplit` from the devel version of `data.table` ie. `v1.9.5`.  Here also, we use the same `regex`.  In addition, there is option to convert the output columns into different `class`.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(totallong)[, c('Crime', 'Year') := tstrsplit(Crime_Type, 
    "(?<=[^0-9])(?=[0-9])",  perl=TRUE, type.convert=TRUE)]
#   Crime_Type Crime Year
#1:     MURD11  MURD   11
#2:    NEG_M11 NEG_M   11
```

If we don't need the 'Crime_Type' column in the output, it can be assigned to `NULL`

```
totallong[, Crime_Type:= NULL]
```

NOTE: Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table)

---

Or a faster option would be `stri_extract_all` from `library(stringi)` after collapsing the rows to a single string ('v2').  The alternate elements in 'v3' can be extracted by indexing with `seq` to create new `data.frame`

```
library(stringi)
v2 <- paste(totallong$Crime_Type, collapse='')
v3 <- stri_extract_all(v2, regex='\\d+|\\D+')[[1]]
ind1 <- seq(1, length(v3), by=2)
ind2 <- seq(2, length(v3), by=2)
d1 <- data.frame(Crime=v3[ind1], Year= v3[ind2])
```

#### Benchmarks

```
v1 <- do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(c('MURD', 'NEG_M'), 11:15), sep=''))
set.seed(24)
test <- data.frame(v1= sample(v1, 40525992, replace=TRUE ))

system.time({
   v2 <- paste(test$v1, collapse='')
   v3 <- stri_extract_all(v2, regex='\\d+|\\D+')[[1]]
   ind1 <- seq(1, length(v3), by=2)
   ind2 <- seq(2, length(v3), by=2)
   d1 <- data.frame(Crime=v3[ind1], Year= v3[ind2])
 })
 #user  system elapsed 
 #56.019   1.709  57.838
```

#### data

```
totallong <- data.frame(Crime_Type= c('MURD11', 'NEG_M11'))
```

Comment: Both those commands are giving errors first goes in a infinite loop and I have break the program.. waited for 5 min. The second is giving a error "Error in strsplit(Crime_Type, "(?<=[^0-9])(?=[0-9])", perl = TRUE, type.convert = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (type.convert = TRUE)"

Comment: @SudhirBapat  As I said I am using the devel version of data.table.  I assume the error is with `tstrsplit`.

Comment: @SudhirBapat [This](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) is the link that gives the instructions to install the devel version of data.table

Comment: @SudhirBapat I think the `tstrsplit` should be very fast if you can install the devel version.  Also, do you have any other patterns in the 'Crime_Type' column?

Comment: Given the size of the dataset (OP mentioned 40 million rows in a comment!), you could probably speed up the `data.table` method even further via `, by=Crime_Type]`.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee  Thanks, I haven't tested it with a big dataset.  I will try with one.

Comment: Once i converted the wide file (all crime types '9' in columns) to a long file using 'gather' o push them in one column the file size is going from 300MB to 8 GB. The file I am working on is 8GB. do you that is the problem. How do i convert it to a data.table for faster processing?

Comment: @SudhirBapat The size could be a problem.  Can you try with `stri_extract_all`?  Instead of the do.call(, may be `vec <- unlist(lst, use.names=FALSE); indx <- seq(1, length(vec), by=2); indx2 <- seq(2, length(vec), by=2); d1 <- data.frame(Crime=vec[indx], Year=vec[indx2])`

Comment: @SudhirBapat  I tried the `stri_extract_all` on a similar dataset like yours with the nrows as you mentioned.  It took around a minute to do this.  Would this be ok?

Comment: Thanks Guys.. solved the problem, the command worked beautifully. the problem was data size i had messed up in the 'merge' command creating duplicated increasing the file size, fixed that and now the same command works great.. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: yup clicked the thumps up :) .. not sure where I mark the problem as closed?